# translating from javascript to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, translation

i'm trying to translate code from javascript to jquery and i need a little help

so , i have this code:

```
$('input[type=file]#upload_input_general_uploader').change(function(e){
    var browserName=navigator.appName;
    if (browserName=="Microsoft Internet Explorer"){
        var myFSO = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
        var filepath = document.upload.file.value;
        var thefile = myFSO.getFile(filepath);
        var size = thefile.size;
    }
}
```

and i tried to translate it to jquery , that's what i got but that seems to not work

```
$('input[type=file]#upload_input_general_uploader').change(function(e){
    $browserName=navigator.appName; 
    if ($browserName=="Microsoft Internet Explorer"){
        $myFSO = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
        $filepath = document.$(this).val();
        $thefile = $myFSO.getFile($filepath);
        $filesize = thefile.size;
    }
}
```

e.g for those who asked why - i need this code to be with jquery to be dynamic , i need to work with $(this) because this function get active for few inputs.
so , what's the problem here?

Comment: You dont `translate to jquery`, jquery isnt another language, it IS javascript. There is no benefit in changing working code to use a library.

Comment: to continue TJHeuvel's message, if there *is* an issue, what are you trying to do, and which part isn't working. The reason to use a framework like jQuery is to normalize cross-browser inconsistencies and make tasks easier to code.

Comment: The first piece of code already uses jQuery, so I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Putting a dollar signs in front of things doesn't make them into "jQuery"

Comment: i know , i meant to jquery style..

Comment: `$ != jQuery`.  Only prefix variable names with `$` if you have a reason to do so, not simply to make your code look more jQuery. ;-)

Comment: I think Mor just meant `update JS to use jQuery more`, not `translate`.  There can definitely be a benefit to changing working code, such as improving readability and maintainability.  In the case of adding more jQuery code, you could be correcting functionality that was not cross-browser.

Comment: The dollar sign is a valid character in JavaScript variable names, and has no special action when added to a name.  Also, `$browserName` will make a variable in global scope, because there is no `var` before it.

Comment: `document.upload.file.value` may actually be more efficient than doing `$(this).val()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
$('input[type=file]#upload_input_general_uploader').change(function(e){
    if ($.browser.msie){
        var myFSO = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
        var filepath = $(this).val();
        var thefile = myFSO.getFile(filepath);
        var size = thefile.size;
   }
}
```

You don't really need to translate it if you don't need to. It's all javascript.

Comment: this function get active by few inputs , so i need to work with $(this) , how can i do that?

Comment: @MorSela What are you expecting `$(this)` to be?

Comment: as you can see $('input[type=file].upload_input_general_uploader') it's a file input

Comment: @MorSela OK, so you need the value, I think. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Start with this line:

```
document.$(this).val();
```

`$` is not a property of `document`, so you'll get an error like `TypeError: undefined_method` when that line is executed.

Comment: i always use it this way , can you explain what i got to do and how to fix it to work?